# Project looks completely different on a mobile device

Tags: html, css, viewport

I have a problem when loading the mockup of my project on an iPhone. 
The problem is that on my mobile device, most 100% containers seem to have some kind of a right margin or padding, which leads to content crash.
I really think that probably this is due to "viewport" stuff, which I don't know for now, but anyway, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

when seen your screenshot, Your code is up to date, when I put my image in your code then it's working fine, so you can check your image width and check css 
check with this #0a1a19 url("../img/img2.png") no-repeat scroll center center / 100% 100%;

If you want to make responsive then use bootstrap  and you can get from here....[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

But you are used custom css so you need to use media query for different layouts like, tablet, mobile, etc...

and one more thing if you not getting perfect layout in your mobile view then must check your media query for mobile view.

Note: always use % (not px) to give the width of any image.

Comment: Jack, thanks. But did you check everything on a mobile device? The thing is that I put % and the image shrinks. And still I have a right margin.

Comment: Yes, I did so that's why I asking you need to check your media query because your layout is not responsive.

Comment: Do you mean the one for the retina-image? Or just in general? (Cause the site is not going to be responsive.

Comment: I don't know friend you are using retina image or what but you can check once adding this in your header class `background-size: cover;` may be help and when occurs this type of error then have lots of thing we make wrongly or either override the css with diffenrent class or id, and when it's occur then we not get our perfect layout.

Answer (score 0):

.header__inner has fixed width, change width to 100% and remove padding for mobile devices:

```
@media <params go here> {  
  .header__inner, .header__inner_mod {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjwbYp)

Comment: Artem, please, what should be indicated in <params go here>?

Comment: @SergeyZ please check codepen, it is the existent media query, just added that classes to it

Comment: Sorry, Artem. Didn't notice codepen included. The thing is that, on the same page with the header I have section with fixed width and the same padding. Well, I've included them in the media-query and it didn't workout.

Comment: @SergeyZ please update your example and post a link with all related content

Comment: what if I store the project on some cloud storage?